# Get specific number of url inside post body

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, get, numbers

I have a forum and I want to make a Context Menu to topics. I want to remove all the "Edit, Quote, Delete, etc" buttons and replace with the menu, [like this one](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html)

So, my problem is how to make the context menu get the number of the post to function in that exact post. 
I'm using Forumotion service. Take this forum as [example](http://help.forumotion.com/)
Using jQuery and/or Javascript, is that possible?

Waiting.
Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [`build` callback option](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/docs.html#options-build). It is passed a reference to the clicked element, from which you can extract the post number.